# Why doesn't this this instance declaration work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a datatype to represent an abstract syntax tree in Haskell. I've been reading various things about free monads, GADTs, mixing Typeable/Dynamic and other possible solutions to this problem, but I'm mainly curious if the solution I had came up with is workable (even if extensions are required), and if not, why not?

Essentially I've got a typeclass like:

```
data AST a b = AST a b
data Atom a = Atom a

class Eval e where
    eval :: e a -> a
instance Eval Atom where
    eval (Atom a) = a
```

Then for an Eval instance for AST, I want something like:

```
instance Eval (e1 (a -> b)), Eval (e2 a) => Eval (AST b) where
    eval (AST f x) = eval f $ eval x
```

In English, being an instance of `Eval b` denotes that something can be evaluated to a `b`, and I want an AST to be an instance of `Eval b` only if its first argument can be evaluated to `a -> b` and its second argument can be evaluated to an `a`. So the idea is an AST isn't necessarily typesafe, but if it isn't typesafe then it isn't an instance of Eval, so if you had code that called eval on a non-typesafe AST it wouldn't compile. Or even just make a function like

```
typecheck :: Eval e => e a -> e a
typecheck = id
```

as a static test. I'm assuming this isn't possible, considering all the other things I'm seeing on representing ASTs, but why isn't it? Can any extensions make this basic idea workable? A major requirement for what I'm doing is that I need to be able to generate ASTs at runtime, convert the AST to text and inspect it afterwards (so I'll need some NamedFunction datatype obviously), and I need to be able to easily represent arbitrary pointfree Haskell expressions with it (so anything that can be built up of some arbitrary but finite set of primitive functions/values, but no let/where/case/lambdas/etc).

EDIT: I feel like part of the problem is inferring that AST should be an instance of `Eval b` in the above case. In the case of `Atom`, I simply state `instance Eval Atom where`, but for AST if I have `instance ... => Eval AST where` then I haven't really stated that it's an `Eval b` specifally, just an `Eval`, and it won't compile anyway without one more argument to `AST`, so maybe the problem is somewhere there, but I'm still not really sure if there's no way to tell the compiler what I'm really after.

Comment: Forget `e1` and `e2`; even `instance (Eval (AST (a -> b)), Eval (AST a)) => Eval (AST b)` won't work, because `a` shows up only on the left, not on the right. This is very problematic for the type checker, because if you allow this, you can't guarantee that instance resolution will terminate. See [`UndecideableInstances`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances) about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar to what you attempted in your posted question using either `TypeFamilies` and `FlexibleContexts` or `FunctionalDependencies`, `FlexibleInstances`, and `MultiParamTypeClasses`.

`TypeFamilies` and `FunctionalDependencies` are both mechanisms by which the type checker can determine one type based entirely on another type. These will solve two problems for us. The first problem, which you encountered, is that we can't get the types `a` and `b` out of a type `a->b` in an instance declaration for a class. The second problem is that we need to be able to tell, from the type of an expression, what type it evaluates to. `TypeFamilies` allows us to make type level functions that can deconstruct a type. `FunctionalDependencies` allows us to declare that a type can be recovered from another type.

*Edit:* `TypeFamilies` delivers a much nicer solution than `FunctionalDependencies`.

**TypeFamilies**

Using `TypeFamilies`, we can extract the needed types from the types

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}
module Main (
    main
) where

data App ef ea = App ef ea
    deriving (Show)

data Atom a = Atom a
    deriving (Show)

class Eval e where
    -- The type of what an expression evaluates to can be determined from the type of the expession
    -- V is a type function that gets this type from the type of the expression
    type V e :: *
    eval :: e -> V e

instance Eval (Atom a) where
    type V (Atom a) = a
    eval (Atom a) = a

-- the class of functions from a to b
-- The only allowed f is (a->b)
-- This creates two type functions, A and B, which can be used to get the type arguments to ->
class (f ~ (A f -> B f)) => F f where
    type A a :: *
    type B b :: *

instance F (a->b) where
    type A (a->b) = a
    type B (a->b) = b

instance (Eval ef, F (V ef), Eval ea, V ea ~ A (V ef)) => Eval (App ef ea) where
    -- B (V ef) is the only thing that requires UndecidableInstances.
    -- It is probably decidable.
    type V (App ef ea) = B (V ef)
    eval (App ef ea) = eval ef $ eval ea
```

Usage requires the types of polymorphic types to be specified explicitly due not only to the monomorphism restriction, but also to the fact that `App (Atom (Integer->Integer)) (Atom Int)` is a legal type, despite the fact that `Integer->Integer` can't be applied to `Int`.

```
-- Example code

instance Show (a->b) where
    show _ = "->"

test1 :: (Num n) => App (Atom (n->n)) (Atom n)
test1 = App (Atom (+1)) (Atom 3)

test2 = App (App (Atom ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int)) (Atom (1 :: Int))) (Atom (3 :: Int))

test3 = App (Atom reverse) (Atom "abc")

main = do
    print test1
    print $ eval test1
    putStrLn ""
    print test2
    print $ eval test2
    putStrLn ""
    print test3
    print $ eval test3
```

Attempting to evaluate an abstract syntax tree with applications of incompatible types

```
-- This still type checks
appStringToString = App (Atom "def") (Atom "abc")
-- But this won't
fails = eval appStringToString
```

fails at compile time

```
Couldn't match type `A [Char]' with `[Char]'
In the expression: eval appStringToString
In an equation for `fails': fails = eval appStringToString
```

*Edit:* Defining the following, and using it in place of `App` in the examples, lets you ditch all the type annotations in all the examples.

```
app :: (Eval ef, F (V ef), Eval ea, V ea ~ A (V ef)) => ef -> ea -> App ef ea
app = App
```

`app` captures and preserves the type information needed by the `Eval` instance for `App` when constructing an `App`. Expression trees constructed with `app` are correct by construction. For example

```
appStringToString = app (Atom "def") (Atom "abc")
```

results in a compiler error:

```
Couldn't match type `A [Char]' with `[Char]'
Expected type: A (V (Atom [Char]))
  Actual type: V (Atom [Char])
In the expression: app (Atom "def") (Atom "abc")
In an equation for `appStringToString':
    appStringToString = app (Atom "def") (Atom "abc")
```

Adding a similar function for `FunctionalDependencies` doesn't solve the type inference problem, even with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`. This makes `TypeFamilies` the clear winner over `FunctionalDependencies`.

**FunctionalDependencies**

*Edit:* `TypeFamilies` delivers a much nicer solution. This section remains only for comparison.

Using `FunctionalDependencies`, we declare that the type can be recovered later. It doesn't deal with polymorphism quite as well as `TypeFamilies`.

```
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances #-}
module Main (
    main
) where

data App ef ea = App ef ea
    deriving (Show)

data Atom a = Atom a
    deriving (Show)

-- Expressions that evaluate to a
-- The type of what an expression evaluates to can be determined from the type of the expession
class Eval a e | e -> a where
    eval :: e -> a

instance Eval a (Atom a) where
    eval (Atom a) = a

-- the class of functions from a to b
class F a b f | f -> a, f -> b where
    func :: f -> (a->b)

instance F a b (a->b) where
    func = id

-- Class of expressions that evaluate to a function a->b
class (Eval f e, F a b f) => EvalF a b f e | e -> f, e -> a, e ->b

-- This requires UndecidaableInstances, but should be decidable
instance (Eval f e, F a b f) => EvalF a b f e

-- This requires UndecidaableInstances, but should be decidable
instance (EvalF a b f ef, Eval a ea) => Eval b (App ef ea) where
    eval (App ef ea) =  func (eval ef) $ eval ea
```

The compiler can't deduce the type of number when evaluation test1, so the example requires an additional, cumbersome type annotation:

```
-- Example code

instance Show (a->b) where
    show _ = "->"

test1 :: (Num n) => App (Atom (n->n)) (Atom n)
test1 = App (Atom (+1)) (Atom 3)

test2 = App (App (Atom ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int)) (Atom (1 :: Int))) (Atom (3 :: Int))

test3 = App (Atom reverse) (Atom "abc")

main = do
    print test1
    print $ eval (test1 :: App (Atom (Int->Int)) (Atom Int))
    putStrLn ""
    print test2
    print $ eval test2
    putStrLn ""
    print test3
    print $ eval test3
```

Attempting to evaluate an abstract syntax tree with applications of incompatible types

```
-- This still type checks
appStringToString = App (Atom "def") (Atom "abc")
-- But this won't
fails = eval appStringToString
```

fails at compile time

```
No instance for (F [Char] a0 [Char]) arising from a use of `eval'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (F [Char] a0 [Char])
In the expression: eval appStringToString
In an equation for `fails': fails = eval appStringToString
```